# Fullpage.js plugin section position element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js plugin for my website.
I have putted my website logo on every section, But when I refresh the page, the height of the first section is small for a few seconds, and after few sections it is normally.
This is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#f5fbfd'],
            anchors: ['home', 'about'],
                navigation: true,
                scrollingSpeed: 850,
                animateAnchors: true,
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                responsiveWidth: 900,
                    afterResponsive: function(isResponsive){

                }
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
<div id='fullpage'>
    <div class="section" id="home">
        <div class='container '>
                <img class='center-block index_logo img-responsive' style='position:relative; top:0;' src='<?php echo get_logo_by_lng();?>' />

        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="section" id="second">
        <div class='container'>

                <img class='center-block index_logo img-responsive' style='position:relative; top:0;' src='<?php echo get_logo_by_lng();?>' />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

What is the problem?
I think I did not understand how to position elements in the sections.
Thank you

Comment: The image is not loaded and therefore takes up no space.  When it loads, the image takes up space.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer but if i not using the logo everything is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is normal, `FullPage.js` takes some time before formatting the document.

*Some test (Click `Run` repeatedly):*

[With a logo](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/8mkvwbz5/1/) and [With text](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/8mkvwbz5/2/), you can see the text too.

---

A solution can be create a fade effect after FullPage.js rendered:

**CSS**

```
html { opacity:0; }
```

**JS**

```
afterRender: function() {
    $('html').animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
}
```

[The example](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/8mkvwbz5/3/)